# On Sorting Error Coming in Sonata Admin Symfony

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Try to do sorting using translations, have multiple entries in translation table with different languagecode and i am showing only one language code on listmapper.

I try todo sorting with it but error comes :

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQuery::entityJoin() must be of the type array, null given, called in D:\software\xampp\htdocs\meopin_2\trunk\vendor\sonata-project\doctrine-orm-admin-bundle\Datagrid\ProxyQuery.php

Can anyone help me in this ?

Thanks in advance